# PowerBI: How to exclude Visual from Filter?

Tags: filter, powerbi

I have a Table with revenues by year and month from several units. To calculate the revenue by month i use a measure to add all revenues from all units. This measure i use then to calculate the current sum of all revenues and want to compare this to a target. Everything is working fine. But on the same Page i would like to have a table with all revenues from my last years. for this im trying to remove the page filter but its not working.

CalcRevenue = TOTALYTD([RevenueMeasure], Revenue[Date].[Date])

when im applying all filters so select all years, it shows the correct visual but naturaly all other visuals are then showing wrong things.

how can i exclude a visual from page filters

Comment: Grrr, a Friend just sent me a video link which explains how to do this. I had to click on my data slicer, go to Filter, edit interactions and then select "none" on my visual that shows all years. That easy.